# Update order of all affected rows on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the simplified version of the table I have below. Each row has an item_order value partitioned by its parent_id.

| item_id | item_name | parent_id | item_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 523 | fish | 1 | 1 |
| 562 | worm | 1 | 2 |
| 612 | mice | 1 | 3 |
| 251 | cheese | 1 | 4 |
| 723 | ketchup | 2 | 1 |
| 912 | pasta | 2 | 2 |
| 52 | chips | 2 | 3 |

Let's say that I want to set the 'item_order' value of 'mice' to 1.

```
UPDATE
    my_table 
SET
    item_order = 1
    WHERE item_id = 612;
```

I need the table to be updated as below.
(Expected changes are highlighted.)

| item_id | item_name | parent_id | item_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 612 | mice | 1 | 3 → **1** |
| 523 | fish | 1 | 1 → **2** |
| 562 | worm | 1 | 2 → **3** |
| 251 | cheese | 1 | 4 |
| 723 | ketchup | 2 | 1 |
| 912 | pasta | 2 | 2 |
| 52 | chips | 2 | 3 |

How do I update the item_order value of the all affected rows within the same parent_id?

Comment: What determins the item_order number ordering? This value should probably be calculated rather than stored.

Comment: I have a sort of like a directory structure where each item comes after each other based on their item_order value. Whenever a new item is added to a particular directory, its item_order is set to (total rows + 1). This is the case where you would need to change the order of the items in within the directory where parent_id = 1.

Comment: It sounds like your ordering should be based off of the created or last altered date of each item, so you would have a row number for each item determined by its last altered then created dates; you then calculated this on the fly, in a view, and it's always correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an update that gets the item_order from the item_id you want to move.

Only those orders below that changed order also need to move.

> ```
> UPDATE my_table t
> SET item_order =
>      case 
>      when t.item_order = t2.item_order then 1
>      when t.item_order < t2.item_order then t.item_order + 1
>      else t.item_order
>      end
> FROM my_table t2
> WHERE t.parent_id = t2.parent_id
>   AND t.item_order <= t2.item_order
>   AND t2.item_id = 612;
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from my_table
> order by parent_id, item_order
> ```

| item_id | item_name | parent_id | item_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 612 | mice | 1 | 1 |
| 523 | fish | 1 | 2 |
| 562 | worm | 1 | 3 |
| 251 | cheese | 1 | 4 |
| 723 | ketchup | 2 | 1 |
| 912 | pasta | 2 | 2 |
| 52 | chips | 2 | 3 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c41c6fb717dc4c25fcb939f976b18be4)*

Comment: Thank you, this is great but I suppose it doesn't cover all cases. For instance you get duplicate values when you set item_order of 723 to 3. Or 612 to 2.

Comment: Uhm, okay. This solution indeed was designed with the assumption that order 1 is assigned to an item.  As one would assume from the question.  The logic will be more complex if the item can be changed to any order.

Comment: Btw, if you want to order this by some timestamp per parent_id.  Then you could use the ROW_NUMBER function for that.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `parent_id` record with `item_id = 1`, and then update all records whose `parent_id` equals `parent_id`.

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET
   item_order = 1
WHERE parent_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM my_table WHERE item_id = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems like this query sets the item_order value of all rows in the given parent_id to 1. I need item_order value of all affected rows within the same parent_id to be incremented.

Answer (score 1):

You want to move an item in the sorted list. For this to happen you must change the item's sort key to the new position and increase all existing sort keys from that position on by one.

```
set @item_id = 612;
set @item_order = 1;

UPDATE my_table 
SET item_order =
   case when item_id = @item_id then @item_order
        when item_order >= @item_order then item_order + 1
        else item_order
   end
WHERE parent_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM my_table WHERE item_id = @item_id);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it has a few problems that I commented above.

Comment: You are right. My solution does only cover certain change situations and others not. It is possible to adapt my query accordingly, but LukStorms' query is better for this. An alternative would be to do all this in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using decimals for item_order column.

If you try to set the item_order of 612 to 1, decrement its new item_order value by a dummy float.

```
UPDATE
    my_table 
SET
    item_order = 1 - 0.1
    WHERE item_id = 612;
```

Now the table looks like this:

| item_id | item_name | parent_id | item_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 612 | mice | 1 | 0.9 |
| 523 | fish | 1 | 1 |
| 562 | worm | 1 | 2 |
| 251 | cheese | 1 | 4 |
| 723 | ketchup | 2 | 1 |
| 912 | pasta | 2 | 2 |
| 52 | chips | 2 | 3 |

Then go over the rows with the same parent_id and set their item_order to the value of `row_number()` function.

```
UPDATE 
    my_table
SET
    item_order = T2.row_number
FROM 
    (SELECT item_id, item_order, row_number()
        OVER (ORDER BY item_order)
        FROM my_table
        WHERE parent_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM my_table WHERE item_id = 612))
    AS T2
WHERE T2.item_id = my_table.item_id;
```

Here is the result:

| item_id | item_name | parent_id | item_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 612 | mice | 1 | 1 |
| 523 | fish | 1 | 2 |
| 562 | worm | 1 | 3 |
| 251 | cheese | 1 | 4 |
| 723 | ketchup | 2 | 1 |
| 912 | pasta | 2 | 2 |
| 52 | chips | 2 | 3 |

This example above only inserts before the given value. The dummy float would have to be added to item_order for inserting after a given value. Another issue is that all rows within the same parent id are updated regardless of whether they need an update or not.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3f53e6b4218048273cb7a52cc1ed29e3)